# Using moment to filter an array by 'today' and 'tomorrow'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I need to filter an array to get items where at least one of two fields fall today or tomorrow.

In this case, it's two lists:

1. Flights today where either a departure or arrival is today
2. Flights tomorrow where either a departure or arrival is tomorrow

The database information includes times, but the time is irrelevant to the filter, only the day is relevant.

The database fields looks like this:

- departure_date: 1564011360000
- arrival_date: 1564026420000

I've got it working somewhat with the following poor code and plenty of 'no-mixed-operators' warnings. The result is correct though.

```
    const flightsToday =
      _flights &&
      _flights.filter(
        _flights =>
        _flights.arrival_date < moment().endOf('day') && _flights.arrival_date > moment().startOf('day') ||
          _flights.departure_date < moment().endOf('day') && _flights.departure_date > moment().startOf('day')
     );
    const flightsTomorrow =
      _flights &&
      _flights.filter(
        _flights =>
        _flights.arrival_date < moment().endOf('day').add(1, 'day') && _flights.arrival_date > moment().startOf('day').add(1, 'day') ||
        _flights.departure_date < moment().endOf('day').add(1, 'day') && _flights.departure_date > moment().startOf('day').add(1, 'day')
      );
```

I would be grateful if someone has a cleaner, more compliant way of doing this.

Comment: just based on a first look, I'd say you can also use `moment date between` function. and push all of this into a function with  prototype 
getFlights(dayOffest, fieldsToCompare)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`isSame`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) passing `'day'`as second parameter.

> Check if a moment is the same as another moment. The first argument will be parsed as a moment, if not already so.
>
> When including a second parameter, it will match all units equal or larger. Passing in `month` will check `month` and `year`. Passing in `day` will check `day`, `month`, and `year`.
>
> Like `moment#isAfter` and `moment#isBefore`, any of the units of time that are supported for `moment#startOf` are supported for `moment#isSame`.

Here a live sample:

```js
const _flights = [
  {departure_date: 1564011360000, arrival_date: 1564026420000},
  {departure_date: 1563963930000, arrival_date: 1564011360000},
  {departure_date: 1563877530000, arrival_date: 1563963930000}
  // etc
];

const today = moment();
const tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'day');

const flightsToday =
  _flights &&
  _flights.filter(
    _flights =>
    today.isSame(_flights.arrival_date, 'day') || today.isSame(_flights.departure_date, 'day')
  );
const flightsTomorrow =
  _flights &&
  _flights.filter(
    _flights =>
    tomorrow.isSame(_flights.arrival_date, 'day') || tomorrow.isSame(_flights.departure_date, 'day')
  );
  
console.log(flightsToday);
console.log(flightsTomorrow);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about the format and contents of objects you're starting with, or the desired format & activities on the other side of the sorting…

**here is one approach to consider:**

```
// we'll use this object as an example for what we might expect to receive
// coming back from the DB containing a table that has an id for each flight
// with a corresponding departure and arrival time in a Unix Millisecond
// Timestamp format as you've indicated:

let db_results = [
{ id: 1, depart: 1563991649216, arrive: 1564042049217 },
{ id: 2, depart: 1563995249217, arrive: 1564045649217 },
{ id: 3, depart: 1563998849217, arrive: 1564049249217 },
{ id: 4, depart: 1564002449217, arrive: 1564052849217 },
{ id: 5, depart: 1564006049217, arrive: 1564056449217 },
{ id: 6, depart: 1564009649217, arrive: 1564060049217 },
{ id: 7, depart: 1564013249217, arrive: 1564063649217 },
{ id: 8, depart: 1564016849217, arrive: 1564067249217 },
{ id: 9, depart: 1564020449217, arrive: 1564070849217 },
{ id: 10, depart: 1564024049217, arrive: 1564074449217 },
{ id: 11, depart: 1564027649217, arrive: 1564078049217 },
{ id: 12, depart: 1564031249217, arrive: 1564081649217 },
{ id: 13, depart: 1564034849217, arrive: 1564085249217 },
{ id: 14, depart: 1564038449217, arrive: 1564088849217 },
{ id: 15, depart: 1564078094050, arrive: 1564132094050 },
{ id: 16, depart: 1564081694050, arrive: 1564135694050 },
{ id: 17, depart: 1564085294050, arrive: 1564139294050 },
{ id: 18, depart: 1564088894050, arrive: 1564142894050 },
{ id: 19, depart: 1564092494050, arrive: 1564146494050 },
{ id: 20, depart: 1564096094050, arrive: 1564150094051 },
{ id: 21, depart: 1564099694050, arrive: 1564153694051 },
{ id: 22, depart: 1564103294050, arrive: 1564157294051 },
{ id: 23, depart: 1564106894050, arrive: 1564160894051 },
{ id: 24, depart: 1564110494050, arrive: 1564164494051 },
{ id: 25, depart: 1564114094050, arrive: 1564168094051 },
{ id: 26, depart: 1564117694050, arrive: 1564171694051 },
{ id: 27, depart: 1564121294050, arrive: 1564175294051 },
{ id: 28, depart: 1564124894050, arrive: 1564178894051 },
{ id: 29, depart: 1564128494050, arrive: 1564182494051 }
]

const td_start = moment().startOf('day')
const td_end = moment().endOf('day')
const tm_start = moment().add(1, 'days').startOf('day')
const tm_end = moment().add(1, 'days').endOf('day')

// set up some arrays to hold our ids that qualify for each bucket

let flight_today = []
let flight_tomorrow = []

// determine what group(s) our flights fall into (there will be some overlap since you've indicated depart OR arrive as a qualifier)

for (var i = db_results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (moment(db_results[i].depart, 'x').isBetween(td_start, td_end) || moment(db_results[i].arrive, 'x').isBetween(td_start, td_end)) {
    flight_today.push(db_results[i].id)
  }
  if (moment(db_results[i].depart, 'x').isBetween(tm_start, tm_end) || moment(db_results[i].arrive, 'x').isBetween(tm_start, tm_end)) {
    flight_tomorrow.push(db_results[i].id)
  }
}

console.log(flight_today)
// expected output: [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

console.log(flight_tomorrow)
// expected output: [24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

If you're able to share more details about the format of input data and the desired format of final data I'd be happy to make some updates.

Play around with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/dusthaines/bq17zx5t/71/